# Set current working directory when opening vim

Tags: neovim, working-directory

When opening neovim via nvim /path/to/directory I want the current working directory of vim to be set to the given path instead of the current path of my terminal.

When opening a file instead it would make sense to me that the current working directory is set to the parent directory and when opening a new file or without arguments the default behavior would be fine.

Is there any option to accomplish something like this? I am aware of autochdir but it does not seem like what I want.

Background is that I want my fuzzy finder to look for file in the correct location when opening vim without having to remember to cd into that directory first.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do this through configuration (i.e. in your vimrc) or more of an as-needed, adhoc basis? The latter can be done with command line params: `vim -c "lcd $PWD" /some/file`.

Comment: I want this as a default configuration rather than a command like the above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you're in an environment that uses the PWD environment variable then you can use that with the `:cd` command in a `VimEnter` autocommand. For example...

```
augroup cdpwd
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * cd $PWD
augroup END
```

This will run once after Vim/NeoVim first initializes.

(Tested successfully with an init.vim file containing only the above.)

Comment: Thank you looks like what I wanted!

Comment: Great! You're welcome.