# Neovim does not cd to directory passed in as argument

Tags: neovim, working-directory

When I start up neovim with a directory as argument, `:pwd` is still set to the directory from where I ran neovim. I would expect it to have `cd`ed to the argument's directory. I wouldn't expect that to happen for file arguments, but for directories, yes. NERDTree does open with the provided directory argument.

I've tried `nvim --clean some/project/path` too, it gives the same result.

This question is closely related [Set current working directory when opening vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34871/set-current-working-directory-when-opening-vim)

However, running `:cd $PWD` on `VimEnter` does not seem to work for me. I've put in `init.lua`:

```lua
local aug_cd_working_dir = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("__cd_working_dir__", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("VimEnter", {
    group = aug_cd_working_dir,
    command = ":cd $PWD",
})
```

It does not change the working directory, though. That makes sense, because if neovim cd's to the current directory of the shell on startup, `$PWD` should be exactly the same and not produce a different result.

Can anyone solve this?

I'm running neovim v0.9.5

Comment: Remark: I can reproduce the behavior for Neovim but not for Vim. Can you tell us which version of Vim you are using?

Comment: sure, I'm running nvim 0.9.5. Post edited

Comment: I'm not sure either program is intended to change directory to a path argument. Perhaps you forgot to mention that you use `autochdir`?

Comment: No, I don't use `autochdir` @D.BenKnoble. I'm wondering why it wouldn't be intended to change directory to a path argument. What's the point of a directory as path argument otherwise?

Comment: Directories are editable via netrw (and are “just special files”). What would the behavior be if I passed multiple directories?

Comment: Right, that wouldn't work. I find it cumbersome to have to cd to the folder I want as the cwd. But perhaps that's just a matter of habit.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble actually what is the goal when passing multiple directories?

Comment: Every argument gets added to the args list (`:help arglist`). With editable directories, it's just "another thing I might want to edit." In this case, "edit" might mean something different than normal, but that's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the following line to `init.vim`

```
let s:hasfolder=1
let g:foldertogo = '.'

function s:parse_arguments()
  let i = 1
  while i < len(v:argv)
    if v:argv[i][0] == '-'
      let i = i + 2
    else
      let path = v:argv[i]
      if path[len(path)-1] == '\' || path[len(path)-1] == '/'
        let path = path[:-2]
      endif
      if finddir(escape(fnamemodify(path, ':t'), ' '), escape(fnamemodify(path, ':h'), ' ')) != ''
        let s:hasfolder = 1
        let g:foldertogo = v:argv[i]
        break
      else
        let s:hasfolder = 0
      endif
      let i = i + 1
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction

call s:parse_arguments()

if s:hasfolder
  augroup FolderToGo
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :execute "cd " . g:foldertogo
  augroup END
endif
```

Here are my observation about the behavior of Vim and Neovim concerning that aspect:

- Vim 9.1 on Windows change to directory
- gVim 9.1 on Windows change to directory
- Vim 9.1 on Linux *don-t change* to directory
- gVim 9.1 on Linux *don't  change* to directory
- Vim 8.2 on Windows change to directory
- gVim 8.2 on Windows change to directory
- Neovim 0.95 on Windows *don't change* to directory
- Neovim 0.95 on Linux *don't change* to directory

Summary:

- It seems it change to folder only for Vim under Windows

Comment: Thank you for that script! Right, parsing the arguments and changing to a directory, if it was provided. I keep wondering though, isn't that an expected behavior for passing directories anyway and shouldn't vim behave that way by default?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-). If the solution solves your problem maybe you could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It let readers know that the solution is worth reading and it help the question to rest :-)

Comment: Yes, it is one solution to the problem. Nevertheless it's really confusing that it's not the default behavior and then I wouldn't need an entire script to achieve that. But probably that's better asked on the respective github repos.

Comment: Indeed since the behavior of the original Vim is as you expect from Vim :-)

Comment: Wait @Vivian, it doesn't work in Vim for me either. I mean calling `vim --clean /some/path` doesn't change directory. Does it for you? I'm on Vim 9.0.

Comment: I'm on a business trip. I'll report what I observe on different version and OS when I'll be home probably this week-end :-)

Comment: I have updated the answer and inserted the results of my tests :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed breakdown!

Answer (score 0):

Some options based on comments:

- use `'autochdir'` (I don't like it, but you might)
- `(cd the-dir && vim …)` to set the directory when launching vim, but keep your shell's directory
- `:cd the-dir` as needed

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I've come to realize that it's easy to cd to the desired directory once and then save a session. The session can be easily restored with an argument, and then I don't need to cd again to that directory.